# Get all users belonging to a Role/Roles

Tags: spring, spring-security

I am using Spring Security and I need to query for all users belonging to a particular role.  How can I do this?

So basically something like this

```
List<User> users = ????.getUsersBelongingToRoles('ROLE_MANAGER', 'ROLE_USER');
```

Comment: Write a query which does this for you, it isn't supported out-of-the-box by Spring Security.

Comment: Yes, this is what I did in the end.  It was a pain because we use Hibernate so I had to write domain objects for Users, Groups, and GroupAuthorities (including an implicit join table for GroupMembers).

Comment: If you use hibernate you already should have those classes, if you didn't why did you add them? Why not a simple sql query instead of doing everything with hibernate.

Comment: Oh, we are using the JdbcUserDetailsManager for authentication, which uses SQL under the hood but not our code.  Thats why.